# API for Scientific Literature Search

Tags: literature-search, bibliometrics, doi

I have to dig through a large number of scientific papers (~26K), all with DOI links. I've built a small Python script for searching through the papers. Now I want to have more data about those papers. For example, where the authors are from (country or university) or, at least, retrieving the DOI link for the papers (not all of them have metadata).

One approach might be as follows:

```
(1) Get the DOI link (from a library, for example)
(2) Retrieve the information about the author(s).
```

Is there an API or a Python library that could help with that? I've looked at the Elsevier API, but it seems to be just for Elsevier papers. Web of Science isn't helpful, as they haven't much papers for my field (Information Systems).

Mendeley, Citavi or Zotero aren't really the options, as I want to do that somehow "automatically".

Comment: For some options, see [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/47197/12391) to a related question. However, none of them will provide you with a perfect solution. At this point, expect to perform a lot of manual work in addition to _some_ level of automation.

Comment: Check also [ORCID API](https://postman.orcid.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CrossRef [has an API](https://api.crossref.org/swagger-ui/index.html), and this will resolve metadata for most papers. (Not all DOIs are registered through CrossRef, but it's going to cover most of the cases you want.)

However, it may not have all the detail you need - it won't always have author affiliation, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that any scholarly citation database that covers all of science and provides an API that will give you author affiliations.

If you are working in biomedicine, though, you're in luck: PubMed has both an API with DOI search, and high-quality author affiliation data.

Answer (score 1):

DBLP might be another option for you. There's a python wrapper to get data from it:
https://github.com/scholrly/dblp-python

Answer (score 1):

Here are some APIs you may want to consider. I found the pybliometrics one which uses Elsevier Scopus to be very useful.
https://github.com/pybliometrics-dev/pybliometrics
https://github.com/ElsevierDev/elsapy
https://github.com/OrganicIrradiation/scholarly